# Condition typescript function handler parameter optionality based on other parameter in the same function

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-typings, optional-parameters, conditional-types

I have some signature of kind:

```js
export const createNestedTransactions = <T>(
  clients: [DatabasePoolType, DatabasePoolType?],
  handler: (
    outerTransaction: DatabaseTransactionConnectionType,
    innerTransaction?: DatabaseTransactionConnectionType
  ) => Promise<T>
): Promise<T>
```

My goal here is to provide the possibility for the consumer to provide as many source clients as he wants and I will open nested transactions for those sources. For now, I am playing with max 2 (thus tuple).

I wonder if it is somehow possible to condition that if he will provide both defined sources I could type `innerTransaction` as required (1) and if only one it will be optional (2):

```js
//1
createNestedTransactions([definedOne, definedTwo], (outer, inner) => {
  assert(outer); // outer not optional
  assert(inner); // inner not optional
}

//2
createNestedTransactions([definedOne], (outer, inner) => {
  assert(outer); // outer not optional
  assert(inner); // inner optional and error
}
```

And I wonder if I could extrapolate to a tuple of any size?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
export const createNestedTransactions = <T extends DatabasePoolType[]>(
  clients: [...T],
  handler: (
    ...args: { [K in keyof T]: DatabaseTransactionConnectionType }
  ) => Promise<T>
): Promise<T> => { return {} as any }
```

We store the `clients` in a tuple `T`. For the arguments of the `handler` function, we can map over `T` so we end up with as many arguments as there are clients.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgQxAgRggzlACgexwGwBVJYBeGAbwQC4Z0QAnASwDsBzAX1BPiVQyiEGCFugQBjEExwsAwjJZRJ0lsWgxyFcbXrN2XYFAAeEHAxAxxM+pYZQkUAHJR6UACZCRY5dY0wAPIQwxiBQLG7ovMhomLgEalAA2gC6AHwAFMAwlvhMYSDotIkAdKWEyQA0WTAAFiJu+FAMtJnZ2aXFCAxshZQwiQDSMKwwANZQYDgAZjDltIjRAp6iElIy8iyKPqo8XNkAlBqpMFgMOAC2TJiBqcD7tKcXV1A3R312IACuDCyUHDAYAEsMAwAzAKyiCxuKBTVjuADyij8FH+gIW-FieCIJHB1ihMLhHgA7jg-NDYYo3IioMBgAB6OkARnBdgczlcHmEK226HSiXJhOpFRgAsphBJlRg6Rwn1CDGFrEUDEOpGOFGqwAMDIATCz7KF2aFOV5VipefyCZTqZLpbKmgrNk0VWqNRwgA)

Comment: Indeed it works, thanks! But how would you cast the parameter to be passed to handler?:`TS2345: Argument of type '[DatabaseTransactionConnectionType]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [K in keyof T]: DatabaseTransactionConnectionType; }'`
handler(t1), handler(t1, t2) etc.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Can you share a [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnKlam) which demonstrates the error you are getting?

Comment: Sure, updated playground. Basically, I was referring now to the implementation. How can I pass the parameters to the `handler` which I am calling as a callback to satisfy typecheck

Comment: Sorry, edited your copy, playground link is too long:
`//3 impl
export const createNestedTransactions2 = <T extends DatabasePoolType[], R>(
  clients: [...T],
  handler: (
    ...args: { [K in keyof T]: DatabaseTransactionConnectionType }
  ) => Promise<R>
): Promise<R> => {
  //derived somehow, there is some internal logic  
  const t1 = {} as DatabaseTransactionConnectionType
  const t2 = {} as DatabaseTransactionConnectionType

  //some logic
  if(Math.random()> 0.5) {
    return handler(t1)
  } else { // possible more conditions
    return handler(t1, t2)
  }
 };`